# Phonegap to google play

Tags: cordova, mobile

I have created a web app which contains html, css, js file.....

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1    /DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>ssssss</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div>
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="username" />
    <button onclick="calling()">
        Call ajaxing</button>
        index.html
    <br />
    <span id="hii">see the change here...</span>
    <br />
</div>
```

Now i created a apk using the online packager of phonegap that is available for free.

Can i share that apk on google store or do i need to take some [licencing](http://phonegap.com/support) first and then go for the publishing app on google play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to pay for any support from PhoneGap unless you want the support services they are offering. If you're fine providing your support or relying on community support then don't pay for things you don't need. If you want the extra support promises then you'll have to consider how much that's worth to you.

Before going straight to Google Play have a look at these links. You only *need* to complete the steps that Google will require but the advice from the other checklists will help you make  sure you app will be successful.

http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/register.html

http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/preparing.html

Comment: also see this link to know how to add your signing key through phonegap: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_phonegap-build_signing_index.md.html